# XSLT copies all text

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using the following xsl transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>   
   <xsl:template match="//something">
      <mytag>
         <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </mytag>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces the wished content:

```
<mytag>
   <something ...
</mytag>
<mytag>
   <something ...
</mytag>
...
```

But additionally there are all contents of the xml file around the wished results. E.g. for the source file:

```
<something>Hello</something>
<anotherthing>Bye</anotherthing>
```

I get the result (or something similar):

```
<mytag>
   <something>Hello</something>
</mytag>
Hello
Bye
```

I tested the transformation with java.xml.transform.Transformer and Oxygen.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there's a set of "default" template rules that apply to any nodes you haven't got an explicit template for.  If you're only interested in the `something` elements then the simplest approach is to add a root template that ensures you're *only* applying templates to those, and not to the other nodes that you don't care about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/> 

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//something" />
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="something">
      <mytag>
         <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </mytag>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note I'm also adding a single root-level element around your results, as otherwise the result isn't well-formed when there's more than one `something` in the input).